# What are the most common Vault numbers in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

What vault numbers are most used in Fallout Shelter?

I've created Vault 420 and Vault 666. Then I realized other people have likely made those Vaults too. Is there a list of the most frequently used Vault numbers in Fallout Shelter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking after the statistics of picking a random 3-digit number from a range of 1000 has nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: Except the numbers aren't randomly chosen. The choices reflect the experience, humor, and knowledge of the players. Those attributes are primary in game play, and humor especially so in the Fallout franchise.

Comment: 'Random' as in arbitrarily, not mathematically random (suggesting an even distribution of all possible values). My point is that this *choice*, this *selection of digits* doesn't have anything to do with gaming.

Comment: I read about what constitutes a question and would be guided by your opinion of this conclusion: a good question asks for help figuring out why the game isn't letting you name a character, but a bad question asks what are some good character names. Have I got it figured out correctly?

Comment: Partially, although it's not that black and white, I think (and hope). Asking after good character names is opinion-based, so indeed off-topic (which doesn't necessarily make it a bad question, just an ill-fitting one). Your first example is limited by the game's parameters, so indeed off-topic. On the other hand, if you'd ask for a fitting *in-universe* character name (e.g. for a Khajiit in Skyrim), I think it'd be perfectly acceptable. The bottom line is whether or not a question can be answered using only data from within the 'gaming world' (stretching from the industry to in-game lore).

Answer (score 2):

Bethesda has not released any information regarding the most frequently used vault numbers.

However, in my research I have seen Vault 420, Vault 666, and Vault 777 appear most frequently in media and online tutorials. Similarly, these three numbers appear most often in a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/8rlrf8/what_is_the_most_common_vault_number/) asking the same question. While I cannot verify it, these seem to be the most common numbers for Vault-Tec Vaults.

An honorable mention is any [Vaults which appear in the Fallout franchise](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Vault). I personally named the first Vault I created in Fallout Shelter after the infamous [Vault 77](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Vault_77) U.S. Government Issue Puppet Ration experiment.

Comment: You offer several bits of helpful information, like the reddit link, which, together with your mention of Bethesda, have decided me to contact their creative team.